# jqueryUI hover(slide) repeating over and over

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, slide

I had earlier posted a question about getting some divs to become visible and slide upwards like pieces of paper, and I had had problems getting my JQuery code to work consistently (or at all).

I have now overcome those issues and am more into the tweaking stage.

I have a series of divs that look like file folder dividers.  When hovering over each individual div, I want a separate div to slide out like a piece of paper.  I have used the "slide" function in JQueryUI to achieve this affect.  In my first version, I just had one slide and I found that even after I moved the cursor away the new div remained visible.  I then added a repeat of the "slide" function using "hide" (first was "show") to make the sheet disappear again.  Here is my code:

```
    $("#artwork").hover(function () {
    $("#artwork-sheet").show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
    $("#artwork-sheet").hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
});
$("#websites").hover(function () {
    $("#websites-sheet").show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
    $("#websites-sheet").hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
});
$("#threedmodels").hover(function () {
    $("#threedmodels-sheet").show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
    $("#threedmodels-sheet").hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
});
$("#games").hover(function () {
    $("#games-sheet").show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
    $("#games-sheet").hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
});
$("#movies").hover(function () {
    $("#movies-sheet").show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
    $("#movies-sheet").hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
});
$("#flash").hover(function () {
    $("#flash-sheet").show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
    $("#flash-sheet").hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
});
$("#info").hover(function () {
    $("#info-sheet").show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
    $("#info-sheet").hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
});
```

The initial behaviour is correct; however, the sheet seems to randomly appear and disappear many times whether my cursor is over the div or has moved on (post-activation).

My guess would be is that there is a better way to make the div hide itself AFTER the hover event.  Could someone help or point in the right direction?

Here is the original question if you want to see more:
[jquery slideUp/Down functions only work in firefox with firebug; also, hover function doesn't seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260022/jquery-slideup-down-functions-only-work-in-firefox-with-firebug-also-hover-fun/)

Thanks,

Alan

---

There just isn't enough room inside a "comment" block to provide a useful reply.

(In reply to #1)
Sorry, this didn't work for me.  slideDown is exactly what I don't want - I want the element to appear to be uncovered from the bottom up whereas slideDown makes it appear to come from the top down.  Also, the shorthand did not work at all.  Nothing changed during the hover state.  This was the same type of issue I was having as stated in my first posted Question.

Then I tried just using the "proper" syntax with commas and that seems to work (phew, found a typo before I completed this post/comment).

Any thoughts on why the shorthand version wouldn't work?

I had just cut and paste into my document and commented out the original, but the response was nil.

Thanks for the help, everyone.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, no need to continuously repeat that over and over, simplify all that into one jQuery selection variable, then add '-sheet' to it. Next, you've got your show and hide in the same function, use the .hover syntax correclty by having two functions separated by a comma. Also use .slideDown() as it's much cleaner jQuery. :)

```
$(function(){
    var $hoverbuttons = $('#artwork, #websites, #threedmodels, #games, #movies, #flash, #info')
    $hoverbuttons.hover(function(){
        $(this + '-sheet').slideDown(1000);
    },function(){
        $(this + '-sheet').slideDown(1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: yeah,it's helpful for me for increasing my knowledge..i voted up your answer.

Answer (score 0):

see the hover syntax here http://api.jquery.com/hover/ you need to add comma (,) between two actions and it's better to write them inside a function as given in official docs